# LibGDX FrameBuffer as shader render target

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl

I'm trying to save world space coordinates form fragment shader gl_FragColor output to a texture to use later on using frame buffer but it doesn't seem to work correctly

what is the correct way to do it?

```
    //create method
    fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB888, 256,256,true, true);

    //render method 
    fbo.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, fbo.getWidth(), fbo.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    fisrtShader.begin();
    fisrtShader.end();
    fbo.end();


    texture = fbo.getColorBufferTexture();
    texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge, Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
    textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture);
    textureRegion.flip(false, true);
```

the shader:

```
//vertex shader
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projViewTrans;

varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

varying vec3 worldSpaceCoords;

void main() {
worldSpaceCoords = a_position + vec3(.5,.5,.5);
v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
gl_Position = u_projViewTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}

//fragment shader

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

varying vec3 worldSpaceCoords;

void main() {
gl_FragColor = vec4(worldSpaceCoords.x , worldSpaceCoords.y, worldSpaceCoords.z, 1);
 }
```

Comment: You didn't actually draw anything with the shader. But I can't think of a reason why it would make sense to do this instead of putting the world position in the shader of whatever you're trying to use this for.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm trying to implement volume rendering app using ray casting method, in short this fragment acting as the ending point of the ray so instead of drawing the back face color i try to store the fragment’s World-Space position in a texture as x,y,z coordinates values inside the fragment’s color, `worldSpaceCoords` is used to store the world space position of the cube’s back face positions. the code above gives me this result [libgdx shader](http://imgur.com/a/LlfOE) while i'm trying to get something like this [working shader](http://imgur.com/a/vTaBP).

Comment: If anyone is interested  you can read about volume rendering and the original implementation i'm trying to replicate in libgdx in this blog [WEBGL VOLUME RENDERING MADE SIMPLE](http://www.lebarba.com/)

Comment: OK, I see what you're trying to do. What you need is to draw your mesh between `firstShader.begin()` and `end()`. You are drawing nothing, so you haven't made a pass with this shader. And when you draw it, you need to pass appropriate uniforms to the shader. I don't know how you're drawing your model. If it's with the gdx 3D api, you need to get it to use this shader program, and it will take care of uniforms. You also need to draw it with front face culling instead of back face culling.

Comment: Yes i forgot to render the actual cube!, i was using `modelBuilder.creatBox` method to create the model then get `NodePart` and setting its `Renderable` to render the second shader for the second pass i switched to a mesh based cube so i can apply a shader to it but nothing is being rendered now, i'll experiment with it.

Comment: so i used `modelBatch.render(instance,fShader)` and it doesn't seem to work eather